# Where can I read the EOS.IO white paper?

Tags: mainnet

I would like to read the EOS.IO white paper published by Block One, where can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EOS.IO white paper can be found on the EOS.IO GitHub repository.

[EOS.IO White paper](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md)